# JS Arithmetic calculations using eval are being multiplied

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm creating a basic calculator using prompts. The user inputs a number, an operand, and another number, which will give them the correct answer.

PROBLEM:
My numbers are being multiplied, regardless of the operator used. For example, inputting 5+5 gives me the value of 25.

Why are my eval calculations doing this, even though I have specified different arithmetic operators?

I can't figure out how/why my code is incorrect. Perhaps I am overlooking something crucial as a newbie. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    var firstNumber = prompt("Enter a number", "");
    var sign = prompt("Enter an operand", "");
    var secondNumber = prompt("Enter another number", "");

    if (sign = "+") {
        answer = eval(+firstNumber + +secondNumber);
    }

    if (sign = "-") {
        answer = eval(+firstNumber - +secondNumber);
    }

    if (sign = "/") {
        answer = eval(+firstNumber / +secondNumber);
    }

    if (sign = "*") {
        answer = eval(+firstNumber * +secondNumber);
    }
    var answer = document.write("Your answer is" + answer);
```

Comment: [Operand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand), [Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning values to `sign` within the if statement condition which is wrong. Do this

```
var firstNumber = prompt("Enter a number", "");
var sign = prompt("Enter an operand", "");
var secondNumber = prompt("Enter another number", "");

if (sign === "+") {
    answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
}

if (sign === "-") {
    answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
}

if (sign === "/") {
    answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
}

if (sign === "*") {
    answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
}
var answer = document.write("Your answer is" + answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the operations instead of checking for equality. You need to use `sign == *` or `sign === *`, as using `sign = "*"` just makes sign literally mean `*`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you are doing 
`if (sign = "*")`
instead of
`if (sign == "*")`
so the last comparison evaluates to `true` every time